# Индикатор предлагаемых правок реагирует на собственные правки?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-так-задумано

Предложил описание для метки, которое было отправлено на модерирование. При этом у меня в тулбаре висит индикатор "1 предлагаемая правка ожидает утверждения", при этом моя очередь правок пуста (права для утверждения правок меток хватает).

Я так понимаю висит моя правка, которую я сам не имею права утвердить.

Это штатное поведение?